# how does Array.from with map produce key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm confused about where the value of 'key' is coming from. When I console.log the contactsList each object in the array has a key

When I generate  contactsOnly (by returning each element in the map) I just get an array of contacts without any keys.

If I then call addKeys(contactsOnly) I end up with an OBJECT, not an array and the objects are numbered. With key being undefined.

Is the index from the map function somehow being passed to addKeys?

```js
const firstNames = ['Emma','Noah','Olivia','Liam','Ava','William','Sophia']
const lastNames = ['Smith','Jones','Brown','Johnson','Williams']

// generate a random number between min and max
const rand = (max, min = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min

// generate a name
const generateName = () => `${firstNames[rand(firstNames.length - 1)]} ${lastNames[rand(lastNames.length - 1)]}`

// generate a phone number
const generatePhoneNumber = () => `${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(9999, 1000)}`


// create a person
const createContact = () => ({name: generateName(),
                             phone: generatePhoneNumber()})

// add keys to based on index
const addKeys = (val, key) => ({key, ...val})

// create an array of length NUM_CONTACTS 
const contactList = Array.from({length: 5}, createContact).map(addKeys)
console.log(contactList)

const contactsOnly = Array.from({length: 5}, createContact).map(i=>i)
console.log(contactsOnly)

const contactsAdded =addKeys(contactsOnly)
console.log(contactsAdded)
```

Comment: It's `….map(addKeys)`, not `addKeys(…)`.

Comment: "*Is the index from the map function being passed to addKeys?*" - yes, exactly that is what happens in `map`.

Comment: could you possibly show me where in the docs that's explained?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax: the callback is called with three arguments.

Comment: yes! I just saw that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer this question:

> Is the index from the map function somehow being passed to addKeys?

Yes.

The [`.map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) of an array accepts a callback that will be passed *three* arguments:

- The current array element
- The current array index
- The array itself

So since your function `addKeys` takes two arguments, and you pass it directly to map, it is receiving the current index for it's `key` parameter (since that is the parameter in the second position).